# How do I have multiple exclude conditions?

Tags: django, django-models

What is the correct way to do the following query:

```
sites = Site.objects.all().exclude(itempage__isnull=True or itempage__pk=1)
```

Comment: I would do `Site.objects.exclude(Q(itempage__isnull=True) | Q(itempage__pk=1))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend using Django's [Q Objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) to construct more complex queries.

```
from django.db.models import Q
Site.objects.exclude(Q(itempage__isnull=True) | Q(itempage__pk=q))
```

Q objects also support negation with the `~` operator like so:

```
from django.db.models import Q
Site.objects.filter(~Q(Q(itempage__isnull=True) | Q(itempage__pk=q)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to another way of achieving this. Just chain the conditions using `exclude()`.

```
sites = Site.objects.all().exclude(itempage__isnull=True).exclude(itempage__pk=1)
```

Comment: A bit of an explanation...  The OP asked for `NOT (A OR B)` and this answer does `NOT A AND NOT B` which is equivalent.